# Intel i3 6100 compatible components for a non gamer?

Tags: motherboard, power-supply, cooling, quiet-computing, heat-sink

I want to build an Intel i3 6100 PC. I don't play games at all. Usually, i use the PC 24/7. I do lot of internet surfing and downloading. Sometimes, i use photoshop, i do audio remixing and other normal stuff.

But I am very much enthusiastic about entertainment. So mainly i want to build a budget PC for listening to FLAC/MP3 and watching BLURAY movies. I already have a huge data of 4TB. So please suggest me a good MOTHERBOARD.

I am very much concerned about heat and noise issues. I want my PC to be quiet and works silently. So please suggest me affordable components like -

1. SILENT DEEP COOLING HEATSINK
2. SILENT PSU
3. SILENT COOLING FANS & CASE

The PC should be durable according to my 24/7 usage.

My PC budget is $500 Thanks!!!